# How is ray tracing different from ambient occlusion when hillshading with SAGA?

Tags: saga, rendering, hillshade, shaded-relief

SAGA offers both raytracing and ambient occlusion in its [Analytical Hillshading module](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/ta_lighting_0.html), but doesn't explain how these modes differ. Is one significantly more expensive in computation, and is the output noticeably different?